# How do I make my post content stay within its bootstrap well, or limit line length?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have post information being displayed within a bootstrap well, but if the amount of text is wider than the width of the well the text continues on outside of the well.  How do I fix this?  here is my code:

```
<div class="totalcontainer">

<div class="postshowcontainer col-md-8 well">
<h1><%= @post.title %></h1>
<p><%= @post.content %></p>


</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try adding this to your stylesheet:

```
.postshowcontainer h1, .postshowcontainer p {
     word-wrap: break-word;
}
```